# Expanding CSS in SCSS (Sass) in Visual Studio Community 2022

Tags: css, visual-studio, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-5

I am new to SCSS and am working on a Bootstrap5 project. I can access all the SCSS files but cannot figure out how to expand the CSS (no hyperlink available). Here's an image of one of the SCSS files:

[image]